# Recursive function when reading a full directory doesn't "step down in directory"

Tags: c

The following function is written in c:

```
void store_files(char *pathname){
    printf("pathname = %s\n", pathname);
    char nextPath[PATH_MAX];
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *sd;
    struct stat stat_buffer;
    int fileNum = 0;
    int dirCount = 0;

    if((dir = opendir(pathname)) == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open directory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if(strcmp(sd->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(sd->d_name, "..") == 0){
            continue;
        }

        if(stat(pathname, &stat_buffer) != 0){
            perror(pathname);
        }

        if(S_ISDIR(stat_buffer.st_mode)){
            //Defines archive number
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                if(strcmp(tmpDirPathNames[i], pathname) == 0){
                    dirCount++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //BUILD PATH
            sprintf(nextPath, "%s/%s", pathname, sd->d_name);

            store_files(nextPath);
        }

        else if(S_ISREG(stat_buffer.st_mode)){
            printf("filename = %s & filesize = %ld\n", sd->d_name, stat_buffer.st_size);
            time_t time = getFileModDate(pathname);
            archiveNum[dirCount - 1].fileData[fileNum].size = stat_buffer.st_size;
            archiveNum[dirCount - 1].fileData[fileNum].absolutePath = pathname;
            printf("modification date = %s ", ctime(&time));
            printf("fileNum = %i\n", fileNum);
            fileNum++;
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

I don't see a real need to explain what each of the if statements in the while loop do since they aren't really relevant to the question. But I'll explain the issue I'm having in more detail here:

One of my other function will create a tmp file with a lot of tmpdir.XXX inside it from an extraction process I do on compressed files.

**example of tmp file with a lot of tmpdir.XXX inside it**:

```
tmp
  ->tmpdir.XXX
      ->TestFolder1
      ->TestFolder2
  ->tmpdir.XXX
      ->TestFolder3
      ->TestFolder4
```

The propose of my function is I want to extract information from every file in tmp. Right now, the function is fine in going into the first `tmpdir.xxx` and go through all the folders in that fine, i.e. `TestFolder1 and TestFolder2`. However, it doesn't go into the second tmpdir.XXX because this happens: (what `printf("pathname = %s\n", pathname);` prints):

```
pathname = /mnt/c/Users/.../Desktop/.../.../.../Project2/tmp
pathname = /mnt/c/Users/.../Desktop/.../.../.../Project2/tmp/tmpdir.JlzQFY
pathname = /mnt/c/Users/.../Desktop/.../.../.../Project2/tmp/tmpdir.JlzQFY/Testfile1in2
pathname = /mnt/c/Users/.../Desktop/.../.../.../Project2/tmp/tmpdir.JlzQFY/Testfile2in2
pathname = /mnt/c/Users/.../Desktop/.../.../.../Project2/tmp/tmpdir.JlzQFY/tmpdir.QE1nk2
```

Notice the last print, it tacks on the next tmpdir.XXX onto the first one. I dont really understand what's going on here and ive been staring at this for ages trying to work it out.

Comment: A debugger will have huge payoffs for this. I'd be particularly interested in what `dirCount` holds, and what purpose you believe it is supposed to be fulfilling. That it is local to the activation, restarting at zero with each recursion, yet clearly indexes *global* arrays, has a particularly pungent code aroma. Even stronger aroma, what happens when the first non-dot-alias object you process is a regular file? What value is the local `dirCount` (0), and therefore what havoc will ensue with things like `archiveNum[dirCount - 1].fileData[fileNum].size = stat_buffer.st_size;` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig dirCount is a way for me to keep track of which zipped file I extracted from. E.g tarfile1.tar extracts to ```tmpdir.ABC``` then, going into ```tmpdir.ABC``` I want it to be 1, going to the next tmp.dir, i.e ```tmpdir.DEF``` I want it to be two and so on. I've most definitely implemented this wrong though and I'm aware of that, I'm not really interested infixing it now however because this flawed function right now isn't even reading properly. If it's going through all the files/folders correctly, then it will also become obvious that dirCount isnt working as I intend it to be

Comment: @WhozCraig I can "answer my own question" and show you the struct dirCount is pointing to if you want but that's really off topic to the issue at hand, at least to my untrained eye (i barely have a year of programming experience in, not even, so apologise if im missing something super obvious)

Comment: Don't get lost in the details. When `dirCount` is zero what do you think `archiveNum[dirCount-1]` actually gets you? If `archiveNum` is the base address of some array or allocated sequence, that condition (indexing `-1`) is a recipe for *undefined behavior*. I would (a) walk your code in a debugger, and (b) lose all the extraneous activities until you can actually recursively enumerate your folder tree (just print it). Once you have that working, *then* start the road to actually doing things with the names you're enumerating.

Comment: @WhozCraig ok I will try that. What i dont understand though is the general idea should be good, the only explanation on why tmpdir.XX would get tacked onto another one would be closedir() isn't called properly, which I dont see why. But I guess ill  try to just focusing on making that work for now

Comment: Btw, depending on your architecture, I find using the `d_type` member of your dir structure tested against `DT_DIR` and `DT_REG` to be much more reliable. Believe it or not, on my MacOS rig `S_ISDIR(stat_buffer.st_mode)` even on regular files, still returns true, which boggles my mind. Short version: consider `if(sd->d_type == DT_DIR)`

Comment: @WhozCraig huh hahaha that's concerning, ill do that actually